# Storyboard and Subclasses

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift, subclass, uistoryboard

I am trying to create a view hierarchy using storyboards and subclasses.
The idea is to have a screen linked to the base class (which is in turn a subclass of `UIViewController`, of course) in the storyboard and instantiate the subclass as needed. The subclass always has the same layout, the main difference is in the `viewDidLoad`function.
If I call `self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("menu")`, I always get an instance of the base class, even if I add `as SubClass`.

Is there a way to instantiate a subclass the way I want to?

Comment: Does the viewcontroller in the storyboard has your custom class assigned to it?

Comment: I came across the following article : [How to use dependency injection with storyboards](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-use-dependency-injection-with-storyboards) which uses a `creator` closure to do the instantiation. Perhaps this would also work for you?  `let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "EditUser", creator: { coder in
        return EditUserViewController(coder: coder, selectedUser: user)
    })`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't do that with a storyboard.  You always get an instance of the class that's named in the storyboard.

Instead, create a xib. Put your view hierarchy in the xib, and set the class of File's Owner to your base view controller class.

Then, in code, instantiate the specific view controller subclass you want, and make all the subclasses load the same xib.

Comment: Thank you! I am aware of the method using a xib file, but I was hoping there was a similar concept with storyboards.